# Python Find IP and upload to FTP

Tags: python, networking, ftp

I've been trying to write a simple script to grab my ip and upload it to an ftp server.  I can do it if i use just use a simple string but im struggling at uploading the IP address.  Im thinking something like

```
def testftp():
filename="testing1.txt"  #know this should all be indented
targetfile=open(filename, 'a')

#get my ip, dont think this is the way to do it, but it works in interactive anyways
getmyip=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
getmyip.connect(("google.com", 80))
print(getmyip.getsockname()[0])

targetfile.write("Your ip address is: ")
targetfile.write(getip)
tragetfile.write('\n')

session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.com', 'user', 'pass')
file = open('testing1.txt', 'rb')
session.storbinary('STOR testing1.txt', file)
file.close()        
session.quit()

testftp()
```

I get an "TypeError: expected a character buffer object" error and i've googled that but i cant seem to find anything specific to this example. ehh. So i hit a brick wall and thought id finally post here.  Hopefully someone can help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give more info about the error, such as which line does the error occur. And as for get your own ip, this line may help. `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.

Comment: You should peep https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp/0.1.3 - it's kinda like 'requests', but for FTP. Eliminates the under-the-hood junk that the fairly-dated ftplib relishes in. It's got it's on caveats, but if that is as complex as your ftp activity gets you'll be pretty pleased.

Comment: can you post the traceback?